# Computing launch parameters for hitting a point in 3D with projectile under influence of wind

Tags: plotting, fitting, modeling

The end goal of this problem is to compute functions which describe the launch parameters which are needed to hit a specified goal in 3D in the presence of wind disturbances. This is as far I have come ($\theta$ and $\varphi$ are variables from [the spherical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)):

```
g = 9.81;
m = 10;
rho = 1.225;
Cd = 0.5;
A = 0.1;
theta = 45 Degree;(*0-180 degrees*)
phi = 45 Degree;(*0-360 degrees*)
v = 35;(*Exit velocity*)

(*wind speeds*)
Ux = -7;
Uy = -3;
Uz = 0;

(*Calculations from classic projectile motion*)
EndTime = (2 v Sin[theta])/g + 5;
h = (v^2 Sin[theta]^2)/(2 g) + 5;
d = v^2/g Sin[2 theta] + 5;

(***SOLVE***)

(*No drag*)
EquationsNoDrag = 
  NDSolve[{m z''[t] == -m g, z[0] == 0, z'[0] == v Cos[theta], 
    m x''[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == v Sin[theta] Cos[phi], 
    m y''[t] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == v Sin[phi] Sin[theta], 
    WhenEvent[
     z[t] == 0, {tMaxNoDrag = t, "StopIntegration", z'[t] -> 0, 
      y'[t] -> 0, x'[t] -> 0}]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, EndTime}];

(*With drag*)
EquationsDrag = 
  NDSolve[{m z''[t] == -m g - 
      Tanh[z'[t]]  1/2 rho Cd A (z'[t] - Uz)^2, z[0] == 0, 
    z'[0] == v Cos[theta], 
    m x''[t] == -Tanh[x'[t]]  1/2 rho Cd A (x'[t] - Ux)^2, x[0] == 0, 
    x'[0] == v Sin[theta] Cos[phi], 
    m y''[t] == -Tanh[y'[t]]  1/2 rho Cd A (y'[t] - Uy)^2, y[0] == 0, 
    y'[0] == v Sin[phi] Sin[theta], 
    WhenEvent[z[t] == 0, {tMaxDrag = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, {x[t], 
    y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, EndTime}];


(***PLOTTING***)

plots = {x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. {EquationsNoDrag, EquationsDrag};
LandingPointNoDrag = {x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. EquationsNoDrag /. 
     t -> tMaxNoDrag // Chop // Flatten;
LandingPointDrag = {x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. EquationsDrag /. 
     t -> tMaxDrag // Chop // Flatten;
SetPoint = {75, 75, 0};
Error = SetPoint - LandingPointDrag;
Show[ParametricPlot3D[
  plots, {t, 0, If[tMaxDrag > tMaxNoDrag, tMaxDrag, tMaxNoDrag]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
  PlotLegends -> {"No drag", "Drag"}, Boxed -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  PlotLabel -> v "m/s exit velocity"], 
 ListPointPlot3D[{LandingPointDrag, LandingPointNoDrag, SetPoint}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize -> Large}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.04], 
   Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {Ux, Uy, Uz} d/40}, 0.4]], Red, Thick, 
   Dashed, Line[{LandingPointDrag, SetPoint}]}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

And I get a plot like this, where the dashed line is the distance between the current landing point and an arbitrary setpoint which I want to hit, and the arrow is the wind vector (the ideal curve is included for reference):

[image]

This is where things get tricky. I was thinking maybe to map a great number of landing points and make a function where the landing point in the $xy$ plane is a function of the wind speeds $U_x$, $U_y$, exit velocity $v$, and the angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$ using `FindFit`. I am not nearly sure how to attack this, however. **The final goal is to have some estimated functions where the angles and initial speed are given like functions of the wind speeds, for example polynomial approximations, such that the setpoint is hit as accurately as possible (see equations below).** This makes it possible to estimate the necessary configuration easily on other platforms without the need to solve DE and so forth. **I would like to be able to calculate the parameters $v$, $\theta$ and $\varphi$ on other platforms which only have access to basic math operations, e.g. an advanced calculator. The functions could be 100th degree polynomials, it doesn't matter, but they will have to be stand alone without the need for solving DEs**. I've attempted to clarify this further with the figure below (SP=setpoint).

$$\theta=f(U_x,U_y)$$
$$\varphi=g(U_x,U_y)$$
$$v=h(U_x,U_y)$$

[image]

For convenience, one may put on some constraints, such as $(U_x,U_y)\in [-10,10]m/s$, $v\in [0,40]m/s]$ and $\theta\in [20,70]^\circ$ or something similar.

Any help or alternative solution methods are greatly appreciated.

Comment: (at) Julian: Interesting Project. Maybe it's no a bad idea to simplify the Problem drastically, e.g. to y==0, Uy = 0, and study the evaluation and presentation of the results. Then you can generalize it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use `NMinimize[]` on the results of `ParametricNDSolve[]` like this:

```
g = 9.81; m = 10; rho = 1.225; Cd = 0.5; A = 0.1; rcd = rho Cd A;
vMax = 40;
EndTime[theta_] := (2 vMax Sin[theta])/g + 5;

sol[Ux_, Uy_, Uz_] := 
  Quiet@ParametricNDSolve[{
     m z''[t] == -m g - Tanh[z'[t]] 1/2 rcd (z'[t] - Uz)^2,  z[0] == 0, 
     z'[0] == v Cos[theta], 
     m x''[t] == -Tanh[x'[t]] 1/2 rcd (x'[t] - Ux)^2,        x[0] == 0, 
     x'[0] == v Sin[theta] Cos[phi], 
     m y''[t] == -Tanh[y'[t]] 1/2 rcd (y'[t] - Uy)^2,        y[0] == 0, 
     y'[0] == v Sin[phi] Sin[theta], 
     WhenEvent[z[t] == 0, {"StopIntegration"}]}, {x, y, z}, 
     {t, EndTime[theta]}, {v, theta, phi}];

params[target_, {Ux_, Uy_, Uz_}] := 
 Quiet@NMinimize[ EuclideanDistance[target, Through[#[#[[1, 1, -1, -1]]]] &@
                  Through[({x, y, z} /. sol[Ux, Uy, Uz])[v, th, p]]], {v, th, p}]

target = {67, 72, 0};
U = {-7, -3, 0};
params[target, U]
    (* {1.29988*10^-7, {v -> 36.2713, th -> 0.642614, p -> 0.779455}} *)
```

Testing:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Through[#[t]] &@ Through[({x, y, z} /. (sol @@ U))[v, th, p] /. params[target, U][[2]]]], 
  {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 80}, {0, 80}, {0, 40}}], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point@target}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Direct hit!

**Edit**

This is a **guide** on how to build a model to be able to transfer these calcs to another platform. Please be aware that the full fledge thing requires a lot of computing power because you'll need to solve the ODE a lot of times.

We will solve here for a small bounded rectangle in the target and wind spaces and we will fit (only the velocity, as an example) it with a complete quadric, although fitting larger rectangles may need more sophisticated functions (impossible to know without doing either the calcs or thinking about the physics). Like this:

```
tab = Table[{{a, b, c, d} = {xt, yt, ux, uy}, params[{xt, yt, 0}, {ux, uy, 0}]}, 
           {xt, 65, 67}, {yt, 70, 72}, {ux, 5, 7}, {uy, 2, 4}];
grid = Partition[Flatten[tab, 4], 2] /. {x_List, y_List} :> {x, Last@y};
vgrid = grid /. {x_List, y_List} :> {Sequence @@ x, v /. y};
cc = Flatten@ Table[coef[i, j, k, l], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 2}];
pows = Flatten@ Table[x^i y^j ux^k uy^l, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0,  2}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[vgrid, { cc.pows}, cc, {x, y, ux, uy}];
Normal[nlm]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Testing:

```
nlm["FitResiduals"] // Max
(* 0.0590728 *)
```

So everything **seems** good. You'll need to calculate some intermediate values to be sure, though.

Comment: @belisarious this is good, but my aim is to generalize and create some estimation functions to predict the landing point and hit a given point at given wind speeds. I've tried to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: @Julian You only need to make a function from my answer.

Comment: @Julian Take a look now

Comment: better still, but what I am trying to get are some simpler functions, for example polynomial approximations. Would it be possible to map an area with the function you have made and take a power series expansion (in terms of wind speed/SP) in order to approximate it?

Comment: @Julian Pretty simple. For each possible target point you can sample the `{Ux,Uy,Uz}` space with `params[target, U]` and then build up an `Interpolation[]` for each one of `{v,theta,phi}`. Or use `NonLinearModelFit[]` if you know or presume some particular functional dependence.

Comment: Say I wanted to sample every possible configuration of wind speeds, target, angles and initial velocity (at a specified resolution with some limitations, f.ex. as above) in order to construct an approximation function, how would one do that? Is that possible with `Map` perhaps?

Comment: @Julian it will take take time and memory, but it is possible. The question is "_why_"? You can calculate each solution on the fly, why to pre-calculate them?

Comment: Because I want to be able to calculate the parameters on other platforms which cannot run this type of script. This is why I need a simpler function than the one given