# Numerical root-finding: Find leftmost root in a domain

Tags: interpolation, equation-solving

This is surely a duplicate, but I cannot seem to find a similar question.

I use `NDSolve` to find an InterpolatingFunction `y[t]` which solves a differential equation with some initial conditions.

I have a function `f[t]` defined in terms of `y[t]` and some other stuff.

I consider the function `f[t]` over a particular domain `{t, 6000000, 30000000}`. The function always exhibits the same qualitative behavior over this domain: it decays toward 0 to the left, and oscillates between 0 and 3 to the right. However the location in the domain where it transitions from one behavior to the other is unknown.

I would like to identify the **first time** `f[x] == 1` in my fixed domain. Below I show some examples indicating what the function might look like and which solution I wish to identify.

[image: Three example plots of function]

Obviously a naive use of `FindRoot` is not going to find the particular solution I am interested in, but yet it doesn't seem to me as though this ought to be a very hard problem. I only require 3 significant digits of precision or so.

I use Mathematica 9.0.1.

—

*Note: Edited to include slightly more detail about the `NDSolve` portion of the problem, since it turned out to be relevant.*

Comment: You could record that root by using `WhenEvent[]` in the original `NDSolve[]` like [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75945/193)

Comment: @belisarius Wow, that's a really neat tool that I didn't know anything about! I think I have a working solution using that tip.

Comment: Yup, neat isn't it?

Comment: I suggest posting your working solution as an answer (once you have one :) ). It is indeed a nice trick that hasn't been explored too much in the site.

Answer (score 2):

@belisarius recommended I make use of **the [`WhenEvent[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) function** in the original `NDSolve[]` that produced my interpolating function.

Since my `NDSolve` command finds `y[t]`, but I am looking for solutions to an equation involving `f[t]`, which is not defined until later, I cannot implement this suggestion in a completely straightforward fashion.

However, it happens to turn out that the *maxima* in `f[t]` always occur at the *zeroes* of `y[t]`.

So I use `WhenEvent` to make `NDSolve` record the zeroes of `y[t]` as it solves:

```
zeroes = {};
NDSolve[{y'[t]==stuff, y[0]==a, y'[0]==b, WhenEvent[y[t]==0, AppendTo[zeroes, t]]}, y, {t, 0, 60000000}]
```

Now I know that the solution I want — and no others! — occurs between the left edge of my domain and `zeroes[[1]]`.

So I use `FindRoot` with *two* initial times, one at the left edge of the domain, and the other just a smidgen to the left of the first maximum in `f`:

```
solution = t /. FindRoot[f[t] - 1, {t, 6000000, zeroes[[1]]-1000}]
```

Since `f[t]` is monotonic between those two points, `FindRoot` will stay in-bounds and Newton's method is sure to converge. Hooray!

Comment: Why not use `WhenEvent[f[t] == 0,...]`?

Comment: Because `f[t]` is written in terms of some things that are not yet defined when I run the `NDSolve`, and it would require significant refactoring to change that. Which I could have done, but the solution I posted here worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a starting point to the left of the desired solution:

```
FindRoot[f[t], {t,0}]
```

or

```
FindRoot[f[t], {t,10^7}]
```

of course whatever is the leftmost point defined for your interpolating function.

Comment: This was my initial thought as well, but if the starting point is indicated too far to the left of the desired solution, `FindRoot` seems to take steps which are too big and can wind up somewhere in the oscillating region, or even overshooting the right side of the domain entirely.

Comment: `InterpolatingFunction::dmval: "Input value {6.6*10^7} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."`

Comment: right as you see no guarantee `FindRoot` will find the closest root to where it starts.  The `{x,xstart,xmin,xmax}` form might be useful, but since you are using `NDsolve` anyway `WhenEvent` is clearly the best approach